# Should we worry about being a dumping ground for other sites?

Tags: discussion, migration

We've been getting a fair few migrations lately. That isn't necessarily a bad thing, but I worry that we may end up being a catch all for questions that are vaguely related to interpersonal skills.

In my opinion some of these have been... Well... Not great questions. Some editing and adjustment for scope would be nice.

I'm thinking it may be worth while to develop some guidance for other sites in the network about what we're comfort fielding here.

Thoughts?

Comment: For what it's worth, I know that some of the mods on other sites who are active here asked other moderators to not migrate questions over here for the time being. Not every migration will be perfect - what's the last migration you've seen?

Comment: @Zizouz212 https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/931/59 not necessarily the worst, but the most recent.

Comment: Ah. Haven't seen that one (I've been really busy today, and will be busy until next week ish). Good thing though that Shog put comments below the answers. The question was migrated by someone who was familiar with the site, but aside from that, are you referring to the ELL questions that were migrated (we asked those mods to stop for the time being I'm pretty sure).

Answer (score 10):

I don't think we need to *worry* about it, no... migrations to Beta sites (or away from them, for that matter) require moderator intervention on the originating site, which means that it's pretty simple to get the migrations to stop by having our moderators ask their moderators to stop migrations.

While we don't yet have any pro-tem mods, I have gone ahead and asked the moderators on ELU, for the time being, to *not* migrate questions here. We had three questions migrated in a short period of time and two of them have been rejected in pretty short order with the [third](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/760/are-these-polite-ways-to-ask-for-a-quotation-agreement) sitting at four close votes as of this writing. In general, migrations to beta sites, particularly *early* beta sites that are still trying to figure out their scope are discouraged.

It's much preferred that sites close the question there and direct them our way for a few reasons:

1. Users will likely not have an account here and may not wish one, which means their question may be abandoned if they never appear here to respond to requests for clarification.
2. Questions that are put on hold/closed (other than as a duplicate) are immediately kicked back to the other site which means we can't put them on hold to prevent answers while waiting for more information - something we can do with questions asked natively here.
3. Any answers already on the question may not be written with the framing appropriate here and the users writing the answers may have the same issues as the askers in point #1.

So, while I'm not saying we should ban all migrations - I think the moderators at reasonably similar sites like Parenting or The Workplace may be easily able to learn our guidelines and be respectful about migrations - we should check in on migrations from other sites that seem to be repeatedly missing the mark and discourage them through the mods directly.

I hope no one believes I'm overstepping to address it in the interim. I did [mention it in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38978911#38978911) and had two users agree that it should be addressed, so I did.